# Convert a string representation of a number to int[] in C#

Tags: code-golf, tips, c#

What is the shortest C# statement that will convert a string representation of a number to an `int[]` that contains each digit?

```
string number = "1234";
number.Array.ConvertAll(line.ToCharArray(), c => Int32.Parse(c.ToString()));
number.ToCharArray().Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.ToString())).ToArray();
number.Select(i => Int32.Parse(i.ToString())).ToArray();
number.Select(i => i - '0').ToArray();
```

Can anyone beat my last approach?

Comment: You might want to not specify the language, as this is CodeGolf.

Comment: @phase you have to be kidding me. the language is in the title and the tag.

Comment: @phase's comment refers to the fact that 99% of the "questions" on this site are actually programming contests. However, [the community has decided](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1724) that language-specific "tips" questions like this one are also on topic.

Comment: @Dennis thx for the advice. first post on this site, would normally post on stackoverflow, but that community considers code-golf off topic

Comment: @Dennis I was just about to search meta for that! I do think this would be a nice golf question, if it hasn't been asked already.

Comment: Substract from unicode: https://ideone.com/Z5S43e :D (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/446764/178988)

Answer (score 10):

## 28 bytes

You can make your last approach a bit shorter by replacing the `'0'` by `48`. You can also strip all unnecessary spaces and use 1-char variable names (for example, `number` -> `n`):

```c#
n.Select(i=>i-48).ToArray();
```

Comment: Fantastic - really nails the fact that a Char handles arithmatic operators as a Short http://stackoverflow.com/a/1516639/26877

Comment: The subtraction could also be replaced by `&15` for the same character count.

Answer (score 3):

### C# without LINQ, <strike>*97*</strike> <strike>*86*</strike> 82 bytes

```
var n=Console.ReadLine();int i=n.Length;var o=new int[i];while(i>0)o[--i]=n[i]-48;
```

I've been hanging in the shadows for a while and wanted to try this out. I'm no golfer, or even that experienced with C#, but I wanted to see how small I could get it on my own, without using LINQ.
It's nothing special, but at least I had my fun.

I wasn't planning on posting this at first, since it's much longer than any good LINQ solution and doesn't really belong here, but I'm kinda curious if there is a shorter way to do it without LINQ.

**Edit 1**: Instead of int.Parse it now substracts 48 from the char's ASCII code. Well, that's already much better.
**2**: Now with var instead of string and int[].

Comment: Using `var` instead of `string` and `int[]` also saves 4.

Answer (score 3):

### 76 bytes

```
number.ToCharArray().Select(var=>Convert.ToInt32(var.ToString())).ToArray();
```